# Signal handling in C - interrupt in interrupt

Tags: c, signals

I was wondering if it is possible to be interrupted by a signal when my program is handling other signal at the same time, I tried to simulate it with:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>

void sig_output()
{
    sigset_t set;
    sigprocmask(0,NULL,&set);
    printf("currently blocking:");
    if (sigismember(&set,SIGUSR1))
        printf("\nSIGUSR1");
    if(sigismember(&set,SIGUSR2))
        printf("\nSIGUSR2");
    printf("\n");
    return ;
}

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    raise(SIGUSR1);    
    printf("start\n");
    if (sig==SIGUSR1)
        printf("SIGUSR1\n");
    else if (sig==SIGUSR2)
        printf("SIGUSR2\n");
    printf("end\n");
    return ;
}

void other_sig_handler(int sig)
{  
    printf("start - other\n");
    if (sig==SIGUSR1)
        printf("SIGUSR1\n");
    else if (sig==SIGUSR2)
        printf("SIGUSR2\n");
    printf("end - other\n");
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    sig_output();
    struct sigaction a;
    a.sa_handler=sig_handler;
    a.sa_flags=0;
    sigset_t set,old;
    //blocking SIGUSR1,SIGUSR2
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set,SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set,SIGUSR2);
    printf("blocking SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2\n");
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&set,&old);
    sig_output();
    //adding handles for SIGUSR1,SIGUSR2
    sigemptyset(&(a.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&a,NULL);
    a.sa_handler=other_sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR2,&a,NULL);
    printf("poczatek wysylania \n");
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    raise(SIGUSR2);
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    printf("using sigsuspend\n");
    sigsuspend(&old);
    printf("end of program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and everytime I run this program I get

```
currently blocking:
blocking SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2
currently blocking:
SIGUSR1
SIGUSR2
raising
using sigsuspend
start - other
SIGUSR2
end - other
start
SIGUSR1
end
end of program
```

is it always like that?

Comment: It's really processor and OS dependent.  In general, many CPUs support different priority levels for interrupts such that a higher priority interrupt could jump in while a lower priority one runs.

Comment: POSIX signals are not hardware interrupts, so the processor itself does not come into question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the `sigaction(2)` manpage:

> Signal routines normally execute with the signal that caused their
>   invocation blocked, but other signals may yet occur.  A global signal mask
>   defines the set of signals currently blocked from delivery to a process.
>   The signal mask for a process is initialized from that of its parent
>   (normally empty).  It may be changed with a `sigprocmask(2)` call, or when
>   a signal is delivered to the process.

You can control whether the signal is automatically blocked in its signal handler with the `SA_NODEFER` flag.

Comment: Ok, I must missed that bit of info.

Comment: It's also worth noting (I think it's not clear from the documentation, although it *is* quite logical) that the `sa_mask` you supply to `sigaction` is a mask of *additional* signals to block, not a new mask to set.  So if you (1) ask to catch signal X with an `sa_mask` that explicitly blocks signal Y (and implicitly blocks X because you leave `SA_NODEFER` off), then (2) use `sigprocmask` to block signal Z, then (3) actually catch a signal X, your handler runs with all of X, Y, and Z blocked.

Comment: It may not be clear from the Linux documentation; the OS X (via FreeBSD) documentation is pretty clear about how the new mask is formed.

Answer (score 6):

The order in which these particular pending signals are delivered is not, as far as I know, defined.  However, signals *are* (mostly; there's an exception for `SIGCLD`, which is traditionally done by "cheating") "non-queueing", except for real-time signals.  The non-queuing aspect means that if you have signal X blocked, and then `raise` it twice (as you do above for `SIGUSR1`), you only get it delivered once.

The only ordering documented on at least one system (MacOS) is:

```
If multiple signals are ready to be delivered at the same time, any signals that
could be caused by traps are delivered first.
```

(These are things like `SIGSEGV` and `SIGBUS`.)  In general, you can control the order of delivery by use of the signal blocking masks: unblock any particular signal(s) at some point and those are the ones that can be delivered at that point.

If you do not set `SA_NODEFER`, the blocking mask at the entry to your handler will always block whatever signal your handler is handling, so that you won't have to worry about recursion.

The special case for `SIGCLD` comes from System V, which originally implemented this by resetting the handler to `SIG_DFL` on each `SIGCLD` delivery.  (In fact, SysV did this with all signals, effectively implementing `SA_RESETHAND` whether you wanted it or not.)  The default action was to discard the signal, as if the handler were `SIG_IGN`.  This of course created race conditions when multiple child processes finished before the handler could do its thing.  Instead of a block/unblock model, though, the SysV folks put in a hack: at the end of your `SIGCLD` handler, you would call `signal(SIGCLD, handler);` to fix up the handler.  At that point, if there were any exited children that had not yet been `wait`-ed for, SysV would immediately generate a *new* `SIGCLD`, and your handler would be entered recursively.  This made it look as though the signals were queued, without actually queueing them.

For more on Linux signals, see (eg) http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html.