# Proper signal handling and interrupts

Tags: c, signals, interrupt

Have a question regarding the interruption of a running process that listens to signals. Below is my handler. SIGHUP is used for reloading my config file, SIGCHLD is used to waitpid with nohang on a process it spawns and the others to terminate the process.

```
void sig_handler( int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucontext )
{
    if ( sig == SIGHUP ) {
        reload = 1;
    } else if( sig == SIGCHLD) {
        // TODO
    } else if ( sig == SIGTERM || sig == SIGKILL || sig == SIGINT ) {
        done = 1;
    }
}

do {
    if(reload) {
        // opening files, doing file descriptor stuff
        ... // processing...
        **SIHUP OCCURS! WHAT HAPPENS?** <<<<<<<<<<< Line: 505 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        ... // processing...
    }
} while(!done);
```

My current understanding of signals:

- signal occurs
- complete current operation on line 505. ie: open("t.txt");
- run signal handler code to completion
- return to line 505 and continue

What I am worried about:

- signal occurs
- break out of current code
- run signal handler code to completion
- continue from break out code

**Questions:**

1. Should I enhance my code to block SIGHUP, SIGTERM, SIGCHLD while reloading the config so that I don't have unstable code if a signal occurs? Or is that over-design? (Assuming it doesn't resume after)
2. Say I am in the signal handler for a SIGHUP but then a SIGHUP signal occurs, what happens? (I assume it queues them and runs the handler twice)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if a signal occurs, your current operation isn't necessarily going to finish before the signal handler is called. However, upon completion of the signal handler, your code resumes from exactly where it was when the signal interrupted. And since all your signal handler does is set a flag variable, there's no effect on the code that currently in middle of whatever else it's doing.

**Answers:**

1. Why bother? Your code *does* resume after, and any properly designed signal handler isn't going to destabilize the code.
2. Documentation seems to indicate that the handling of the second signal will be deferred until the first handler completes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10093907/2171689) for details.