# Is it possible a signal handler interrupts another signal handler for the same signal?

Tags: c++, signals

C++ documentation states that:

> "If a signal handler is executed as a result of a call to the `raise` function, then the execution of the handler is
>       sequenced after the invocation of the raise function and before its return. [ Note: When a signal is received
>       for another reason, the execution of the signal handler is usually unsequenced with respect to the rest of the
>       program. —end note ]"

Does this means that a handler could interrupt another handler?

Comment: Signal handling is a sensitive area — the C standard doesn't provide much control over it (and the C++ standard is closely related to the C standard here).  POSIX provides [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) which provides much more control over signals — it blocks the signal being delivered to prevent repeated signals while the handler is active (a second signal of the same sort is held pending until the handler returns, whereupon the second signal might be delivered before control returns). You can specify which other signals are blocked.

Comment: Complement the comment of @JonathanLeffler,  you can use SA_NODEFER flag for controlling whether the signal is automatically blocked in its signal handler.

Comment: This post address this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093907/signal-handling-in-c-interrupt-in-interrupt

Comment: Does 'usually unsequenced' means that the SA_NODEFER is the default value as in the man page "unless the SA_NODEFER flag is used"?